# Nesting dictionaries while looping through data

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary, indentation

I'm having a rather hard problem that I just can't get fixed.. 
The idea is to loop through a part of data and find any indentation. (always spaces)
Every time a line has a bigger indentation than the previous, for example 4 more whitespaces, the first line should be the key for a dictionary and the next values should be appended.

If there is another indent this means there should be made a new dictionary with a key and values. This should happen recursive until being through the data.
To make things easier to understand I made an example:

```
Chassis 1:
    Servers:
        Server 1/1:
            Equipped Product Name: EEE UCS B200 M3
            Equiped PID: e63-samp-33
            Equipped VID: V01
            Acknowledged Cores: 16
            Acknowledged Adapters: 1
    PSU 1:
        Presence: Equipped
        VID: V00
        HW Revision: 0
```

The idea is to be able to get any part of data returned in dictionary form. 
dictionary.get("Chassis 1:") should return ALL data, dictionary.get("Servers") should return everything that is indented deeper than the line "Servers".
dictionary.get("PSU 1:") should give {"PSU 1:":"Presence: Equipped", "VID: 100", "HW Revision: 0"} and so on.
I've drawn a little scheme to demonstrate this, every colour is another dictionary. 
[image]

When the indentation goes less deep again, for example from 8 to 4 spaces the data should be appended to the dictionary that has data which is less indented.

I've gave it an attempt in code but it is not coming anywhere near where I want it..

```
for item in Array:
    regexpatt = re.search(":$", item)
    if regexpatt:
        keyFound = True
        break

if not keyFound:
    return Array

#Verify if we still have lines with spaces
spaceFound = False
for item in Array:
    if item != item.lstrip():
        spaceFound = True
        break

if not spaceFound:
    return Array

keyFound = False
key=""
counter = -1
for item in Array:
    counter += 1
    valueTrim = item.lstrip()
    valueL = len(item)
    valueTrimL = len(valueTrim)
    diff = (valueL - valueTrimL)
    nextSame = False
    if item in Array:
        nextValue = Array[counter]
        nextDiff = (len(nextValue) - len(nextValue.lstrip()))
        if diff == nextDiff:
            nextSame = True


    if diff == 0 and valueTrim != "" and nextSame is True:
        match = re.search(":$", item)
        if match:
            key = item
            newArray[key] = []
            deptDetermine = True
            keyFound = True
    elif diff == 0 and valueTrim != "" and keyFound is False:
        newArray["0"].append(item)
    elif valueTrim != "":
        if depthDetermine:
            depth = diff
            deptDetermine = False
        #newValue = item[-valueL +depth]
        item = item.lstrip().rstrip()
        newArray[key].append(item)

for item in newArray:
    if item != "0":
        newArray[key] = newArray[key]

return newArray
```

The result should be like this for example:

```
{
    "Chassis 1": {
        "PSU 1": {
            "HW Revision: 0", 
            "Presence: Equipped", 
            "VID: V00"
        }, 
        "Servers": {
            "Server 1/1": {
                "Acknowledged Adapters: 1", 
                "Acknowledged Cores: 16", 
                "Equiped PID: e63-samp-33", 
                "Equipped Product Name: EEE UCS B200 M3", 
                "Equipped VID: V01"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this explains the concept enough

Comment: So what *does* your code do, and where precisely does it fall short?

Comment: You need to implement a push-down automaton.

Comment: jonrsharpe It makes a dictionary with keys / lists inside it, but not the correct formatting or order, so I chose to not include a 'result' as it contains pretty many flaws..
@JoelCornett Any examples or a answer? Feel free to post something!

Comment: @Yenthe: What do you mean, "not the correct order"? Dictionaries are unordered by nature. If you want ordered behavior, you need to use a different data structure.

Comment: @JoelCornett I mean that not all the data that I wanted gets pushed in the correct list, neither does every element that I need as a key become a key. There are some fundamental flaws in my logic I'm afraid :/

Comment: Ah. I see. Hold on...

Comment: Looking at your example data, I think a yaml parser would directly read it into the data structure that you want. I don't have python + yaml installed locally to create code for a real answer, but hope that helps.

Comment: @sgauria while I love your idea I cannot use yaml. It is a specific platform, which can not be combined / used with yaml

Comment: I meant that your example data should get parsed as valid yaml already.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give you the nested structure you want.

If you want every nested dictonary, also available from the root. Uncomment the `if .. is not root` parts

```
def parse(data):

    root = {}
    currentDict = root
    prevLevel = -1
    parents = []
    for line in data:
        if line.strip() == '': continue
        level = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(" "))
        key, value = [val.strip() for val in line.split(':', 1)]

        if level > prevLevel and not len(value):
            currentDict[key] = {}
            # if currentDict is not root:
            #     root[key] = currentDict[key]
            parents.append((currentDict, level))
            currentDict = currentDict[key]
            prevLevel = level
        elif level < prevLevel and not len(value):
            parentDict, parentLevel = parents.pop()
            while parentLevel != level:
                if not parents: return root
                parentDict, parentLevel = parents.pop()
            parentDict[key] = {}
            parents.append((parentDict, level))
            # if parentDict is not root:
            #     root[key] = parentDict[key]
            currentDict = parentDict[key]
            prevLevel = level
        else:
            currentDict[key] = value
    return root 




with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = parse(f)
    #for pretty print of nested dict
    import json
    print json.dumps(data,sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

output:

```
{
    "Chassis 1": {
        "PSU 1": {
            "HW Revision": "0", 
            "Presence": "Equipped", 
            "VID": "V00"
        }, 
        "Servers": {
            "Server 1/1": {
                "Acknowledged Adapters": "1", 
                "Acknowledged Cores": "16", 
                "Equiped PID": "e63-samp-33", 
                "Equipped Product Name": "EEE UCS B200 M3", 
                "Equipped VID": "V01"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great solution! If I can nitpick, I don't see a need to use `str.count` to measure the `level`, just use `level = len(line) - len(line.lstrip(" "))`. This code also breaks if a `:` is present in key or value, but that's not surprising (most parsers require the delimiter not be present in either field), so it may be more of a note to OP.

Comment: I believe that what Adam is referring too is exactly why it crashes on me?
I get the following error:
" key, value = [val.strip() for val in line.split(':')]
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack"
But yes, if this works it is probably what I need! Any clue why I get this error?

Comment: @AdamSmith Thanks, i made your suggested edit. it should be slightly more efficient. And i also added `line.split(':', 1)` so it wont break if more than one `:` is present (but results might not be desirable).

Comment: @Yenthe is atleast one `:` present in every line? or maybe there's some blank lines in there. that would probably mess it up.

Comment: @Yenthe try modifying the code to wrap the `value = [val.strip() ...` line in `try: #M4rtini's code here; except ValueError: print line` that may help you debug so we can see the line that's throwing the error. Looks like one of the lines doesn't have a `:` in it.

Comment: @Yenthe i made a edit so that it now skips empty lines. see if that helps. if not, put it in a try block as Adam Smith suggested

Comment: There are both lines without and with : inside it and there are some empty lines too.Example: http://pastebucket.com/36908

Comment: @Yenthe yeah looks like skipping blank lines will fix it if your total structure looks like your pastebin. Every line with data in it has a `:`

Comment: @M4rtini your code doesn't crash anymore but I can't get it outputted.
I've got another function that delivers the data in list format to your function. result = parseTest(listFromOtherFunction)
print(result) gives me "You returned an object I can not encode in JSON: None." Am I doing something wrong then?

Comment: @Yenthe hmm, that might happen if it did not manage to match a indentation with a parent in the while loop. I added `return root` there now. Give it a try. Also the other answer here seems to give the   same result so give that one a try also.

Comment: @M4rtini awesome! I'm almostttt at what I exactly need! Now you get this: "HW Revision": "0" is there an option to place that into one value in place as of 2? The structure is perfect except for all the items belonging to a key. They shouldn't be split up "HW Revision" : "0" should become "HW Revision:0". By the way, already upvoting for this, thanks!

Comment: @Yenthe Not sure if i can modify it to do that. Would it be enough to just add the key into the value also? like this: `currentDict[key] = ':'.join((key, value))`

Comment: @M4rtini it should really show the whole line as a value really, not split by :, as thats a big requirement

Comment: @Yenthe Can you add a full example of how the resulting dictionary should look like for the example input in the questions? I think I've misunderstood.

Comment: I've edited my question or alternatively you can find the layout here: http://pastebin.com/7ngqjUw6

Comment: @Yenthe How would you like the layout to be when you have values, and a new dictionary at the same level, as you had in the other pastebucket link? (Bios and motherboard in that example)

Comment: This is a bigger example.
http://pastebin.com/VmB5EsKq
The data should be within server 1/1 and both BIOS and Motherboard should be seperated

Comment: @Yenthe That structure would not be possible. "Server 1/1" would there be a `set` containing strings (the key:value pair) and a dictionaries ( which can't be part of a set!). The alternative would be to use a list, but even then, it would be impractical to access the dictionaries of that list.

Comment: Hmm I see.. what is the closest structure that could be build?

Comment: I would go with the structure as it is now. Since it fits how the data looks pretty good. Accessing values is fairly straight forward, and if you need to modify it for presentation, do that in a separate step. And you should really go with yaml if you can. It is, without a doubt, more reliable and bug free than this.

Comment: Very well, as this does 95%+ of what I want I'll accept this answer :) And I'll look into Yaml tommorow.. Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 4):

That data format really does look like [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML). Just in case someone stumbles onto this and is fine with a library solution:

```
import yaml
import pprint

s = """
Chassis 1:
    Servers:
        Server 1/1:
            Equipped Product Name: EEE UCS B200 M3
            Equiped PID: e63-samp-33
            Equipped VID: V01
            Acknowledged Cores: 16
            Acknowledged Adapters: 1
    PSU 1:
        Presence: Equipped
        VID: V00
        HW Revision: 0
"""

d = yaml.load(s)
pprint.pprint(d)
```

The output is:

```
{'Chassis 1': {'PSU 1': {'HW Revision': 0,
                         'Presence': 'Equipped',
                         'VID': 'V00'},
               'Servers': {'Server 1/1': {'Acknowledged Adapters': 1,
                                          'Acknowledged Cores': 16,
                                          'Equiped PID': 'e63-samp-33',
                                          'Equipped Product Name': 'EEE UCS B200 M3',
                                          'Equipped VID': 'V01'}}}}
```

For reference:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML
- http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation
- https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint

Comment: Sadly I cannot install or use the yaml module so I would have to request that. This'll be my second back-up as this looks as a nice and easy way though.

Comment: @Yenthe I can't imagine what requirement could prevent you from using this library. Apart from installing it, you could just download the sources to your code base (and add the package to your PYTHONPATH).

Comment: @mooeeeep sadly I'm in a very big, restricted company. I'll have to ask the biggest admins for permission, sadly. It would atleast take a day, if it gets approved..

Comment: @mooeeeep I gave this a try locally and sadly this would never work. It relies on EVERY line having ":", which is not my case and probably isn't for other people either.

Comment: @Yenthe Of course, if you use a YAML parser you need to comply to it's specification. You can prepend the values with dashes `-` to make up a list of strings, you can wrap a line in quotes `"..."` to escape dashes and colons in your values.